# Powershell: What's the right way to output full error messages from New-Item?

Tags: powershell, verbose, new-item

I'm running a `vagrant` winrm command, and am noticing that a command that fails doesn't print out the entire error output...  I thought `|` might be used to expand output from such commands... but after some internet searching, and trying a few options, such as:

- `| fl`
- `| Format-Table -Wrap -Au`

I still get a `...` in the final output of
my error message, i.e. in the part where the command is echo'd.

```
NewItemIOError
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Item -path C:\var\lib\kubelet\etc\kubernetes\pki\ -type SymbolicL ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The above failure is happening for a clear and obvious reason, so I don't need help debugging the issue, but rather, am generally wondering what is the right option to use with `New-Item` to make sure powershell shows me the entire output of its failed execution in automated environments with 10000s of lines of logs.

*What's the simplest way to output verbose error messages from new-item, and similar powershell commands?*

Comment: Isn't the `...` just for the console output? (That is, don't the error objects contain the entire message?)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart it does, as I described below :)

Comment: Correct. It is helpful to remember that, In PowerShell, the _display_ of object _x_ is not necessarily equivalent to the _content_ of object _x_. (Another way to say this is that the displayed output of an object is a formatted representation of that object.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply put - dots in exception message in console are only for display purposes - to not give you wall of text.
If you want to display the **FULL** exception you can use something like this:

```
try {
    New-Item NONEXISTING:\asd.txt -ErrorAction Stop #This will throw error
    Write-Host "If it shows error was not caught"
}
catch {
    $_.Exception | Format-List -Force
}
```

This displays info like below and gives you full info about Exception object :)

```
ErrorRecord                 : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'NONEXISTING' does not exist.
ItemName                    : NONEXISTING
SessionStateCategory        : Drive
WasThrownFromThrowStatement : False
Message                     : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'NONEXISTING' does not exist.
Data                        : {}
InnerException              :
TargetSite                  : System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo GetDrive(System.String, Boolean)
StackTrace                  :    at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.GetDrive(String name, Boolean automount)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.GetDrive(String name, Boolean automount)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetDriveRootRelativePathFromPSPath(String path, CmdletProviderContext context, Boolean escapeCurrentLocation, PSDriveInfo& workingDriveForPath, CmdletProvider& providerInstance)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetProviderPath(String path, CmdletProviderContext context, Boolean isTrusted, ProviderInfo& provider, PSDriveInfo& drive)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.NewItem(String[] paths, String name, String type, Object content, CmdletProviderContext context)
                                 at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand.ProcessRecord()
HelpLink                    :
Source                      : System.Management.Automation
HResult                     : -2146233087
```

For full message or stack trace, just go with `$_.Exception.Message` or `$_.Exception.StackTrace`:

```
try {
    New-Item NONEXISTING:\asd.txt -ErrorAction Stop; #This will throw error
    Write-Host "If it shows error was not caught"
}
catch {
    Write-Host "MESSAGE`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
    Write-Host "STACK TRACE`n$($_.Exception.StackTrace)"
}
```

and it gives info:

```
MESSAGE
Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'NONEXISTING' does not exist.
STACK TRACE
   at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.GetDrive(String name, Boolean automount)
   at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.GetDrive(String name, Boolean automount)
   at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetDriveRootRelativePathFromPSPath(String path, CmdletProviderContext context, Boolean escapeCurrentLocation, PSDriveInfo& workingDriveForPath, CmdletProvider& providerInstance)
   at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetProviderPath(String path, CmdletProviderContext context, Boolean isTrusted, ProviderInfo& provider, PSDriveInfo& drive)
   at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.NewItem(String[] paths, String name, String type, Object content, CmdletProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand.ProcessRecord()
```

PS. If you want even more info:

```
try {
    New-Item NONEXISTING:\asd.txt -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "If it shows error was not caught"
}
catch {
    $_ | Format-List -Force
}
```

This will display all the info including ScriptStackTrace (at which line the exception occurred):

```
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.DriveNotFoundException: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'NONEXISTING' does not exist.
                           at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.GetDrive(String name, Boolean automount)
                           at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.GetDrive(String name, Boolean automount)
                           at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetDriveRootRelativePathFromPSPath(String path, CmdletProviderContext context, Boolean escapeCurrentLocation, PSDriveInfo& workingDriveForPath, CmdletProvider& providerInstance)
                           at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetProviderPath(String path, CmdletProviderContext context, Boolean isTrusted, ProviderInfo& provider, PSDriveInfo& drive)
                           at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.NewItem(String[] paths, String name, String type, Object content, CmdletProviderContext context)
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand.ProcessRecord()
TargetObject          : NONEXISTING
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (NONEXISTING:String) [New-Item], DriveNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 2
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

Comment: I would suggest using `$Error[0]` instead of `$_`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, in a `catch` block, `$_` is designed to contain the offending error; you only need the more verbose equivalent `$Error[0]` _outside_ such a block, to refer to the most recent error.

Comment: Wait, I was just quoting you from another post  so, does one have the edge on the other?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala :) Inside a `catch` block, `$_` and `$Error[0]` are equivalent, so while you may use the latter too, it's both more verbose and less obvious. If I recommended use of `$Error[0]` in a `catch` block in an answer of mine, do tell me - it should be revised.

Comment: It was a comment lol can't remember which one it was but, they posted an answer using `$_` as the error. Will keep that in mind now. Thanks!(:

Comment: Good answer.  I usually use `| Select-Object *` instead of `| Format-List -Force`